# Cómo configurar el archivo my.ini del MySQL que trae XAMPP de forma óptima para importar sql grandes de la forma más rápida

Tags: sql, mysqli

Tengo un archivo SQL de 2.5GB y en 5 horas iba por 23%. Lo que noto es que comienza muy bien y luego se va demorando cada vez más entre consultas llegando a demorar más de 1 min entre consultas. Probé muchas variantes, *me comí a google* y leí mucha documentación pero en ningún cambio que realizaba se notaba la mejoría. Estoy usando el Navicat y la consulta no es más que una copia de seguridad de la DB por lo que solo trae sentencias `create` e `insert`.

Mi ordenador:
Procesador: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.60 GHz
RAM instalada: 8,00 GB (7,86 GB usable)
Utilizo la última versión de XAMPP, xampp-windows-x64-8.2.4-0-VS16

¿Qué variables tengo que modificar y qué valores tendría que ponerle para una mejor velocidad, o hay que hacerle algo en especial a los archivos sql? Acá les dejo mi configuración del archivo My.ini, es su estado por defecto y comentado están las variables que modifiqué.

> Voy a quitarle un poco los comentarios para que no se haga muy extenso.

```ini
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
# password       = your_password 
port=3306
socket="D:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"


# Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
default-character-set=utf8mb4
[mysqld]
port=3306
socket="D:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir="D:/xampp/mysql"
tmpdir="D:/xampp/tmp"
datadir="D:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file="mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer=16M
max_allowed_packet=100M
sort_buffer_size=512K
net_buffer_length=8K
read_buffer_size=256K
read_rnd_buffer_size=512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size=8M
log_error="mysql_error.log"

#Variables modificadada para mejorar la velocidad
#key_buffer_size=384M
#max_allowed_packet=100M
#table_open_cache=512
#sort_buffer_size=2M
#read_buffer_size=2M
#read_rnd_buffer_size=8M
#myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
#thread_cache_size=8
#query_cache_size=32M
#Try number of CPUs*2 for thread_concurrency
#thread_concurrency=8

# Change here for bind listening
# bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6

# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir="D:/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/"

server-id   =1

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir="D:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir="D:/xampp/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "D:/xampp/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size=16M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size=5M
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50

## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
#collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
#character_set_server=utf8
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
#character_sets-dir="D:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"
sql_mode=NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
log_bin_trust_function_creators=1

character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet=16M

[mysql]
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
#key_buffer=20M
#sort_buffer_size=20M
#read_buffer=2M
#write_buffer=2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer=20M
sort_buffer_size=20M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M
#Variables modificadada para mejorar la velocidad
#key_buffer_size=256M
#sort_buffer_size=256M
#read_buffer=2M
#write_buffer=2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
#Variable modificadada para mejorar la velocidad
#interactive_timeout=1
```

Comment: Y que DBM usas? Porque yo uso Navicat y nunca he tenido problemas con DBs incluso más grandes.

Comment: No es claro, el archivo SQL ¿tiene consultas (`SELECT`)? o te refieres a las consultas realizadas después de cargar el archivo SQL. ¿Es un archivo único o cada cuánto lo cargas? ¿Importas a una o a varias tablas?.

Comment: Uso Navicat, y el sql no es mas que un archivo dump donde crea las tablas he inserta los registros. Es un archivo donde se tiene una copia de seguridad de toda la DB.

Comment: Por favor tendrán alguna solución, alguien sabe como darle solución a mi problema.

Comment: Sin saber que le pasa al archivo, no va a ser posible... si es un dump, no deberia tardar eso, ahora el problema puede ser el servidor o tambien algun otra cosa... pero sin ver el archivo, sin saber del servidor por lo menos por mi parte, imposible ayudarte... Probaste partir el archivo???

Comment: El problema no es el archivo, sino la configuración de mysql, en una ocacion lo ise hace mucho tiempo y cambiándome algunos valores al my.ini se resolvió el problema de importación lenta, pero no recuerdo que configuración debo modificar